# SQL fill missing date and null value

Tags: sql, date, join, sas

I am using SAS Enterprise Guide 8.3 to connect IBM DB2.

I want to join and fill missing date and values.

I have a full calendar date table from 1/1/2021 up to yesterday.

Each ID can work 5 days to 7 days a week.

There is no target for Sunday.

4/3/2022 is Sunday.

Code is

```
SELECT t2.ID, 
          t1.CAL_DT, COALESCE(t2.EXPRESS,0) AS EXPRESS, COALESCE(t2.OTHRES,0) AS OTHRES , COALESCE(t2.CPRO_RPT,0) AS Total
          FROM WORK.QUERY_FOR_DATE t1
           left outer JOIN WORK.QUERY_FOR_CPRO_0000 t2 on t1.cal_dt = t2.cal_dt
      ORDER BY t2.ID asc ,t1.CAL_DT asc;
```

[image]

Sample tables are below.

Table 1.

| ID | Date | Express | Others | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 4/1/2022 | 0 | 2 | 2 |
| 001 | 4/2/2022 | 2 | 3 | 5 |
| 001 | 4/4/2022 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 001 | 4/5/2022 | 2 | 2 | 4 |
| 002 | 4/1/2022 | 0 | 3 | 3 |
| 002 | 4/4/2022 | 3 | 3 | 6 |
| 002 | 4/5/2022 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 003 | 4/1/2022 | 3 | 3 | 6 |
| 003 | 4/2/2022 | 4 | 4 | 8 |
| 003 | 4/3/2022 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 003 | 4/4/2022 | 3 | 4 | 7 |
| 003 | 4/6/2022 | 2 | 4 | 6 |

Table 2.

| ID | Date | Target |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 4/1/2022 | 4 |
| 001 | 4/2/2022 | 4 |
| 001 | 4/4/2022 | 4 |
| 001 | 4/5/2022 | 4 |
| 002 | 4/1/2022 | 6 |
| 002 | 4/2/2022 | 6 |
| 002 | 4/4/2022 | 6 |
| 002 | 4/5/2022 | 6 |
| 003 | 4/1/2022 | 8 |
| 003 | 4/2/2022 | 8 |
| 003 | 4/4/2022 | 8 |
| 003 | 4/5/2022 | 8 |

I want the result in Table 3.

| ID | Date | Express | Others | Total | Target |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 4/1/2022 | 0 | 2 | 2 | 4 |
| 001 | 4/2/2022 | 2 | 3 | 5 | 4 |
| 001 | 4/3/2022 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 001 | 4/4/2022 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| 001 | 4/5/2022 | 2 | 2 | 4 | 4 |
| 002 | 4/1/2022 | 0 | 3 | 3 | 6 |
| 002 | 4/2/2022 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 6 |
| 002 | 4/3/2022 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 002 | 4/4/2022 | 3 | 3 | 6 | 6 |
| 002 | 4/5/2022 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 6 |
| 003 | 4/1/2022 | 3 | 3 | 6 | 8 |
| 003 | 4/2/2022 | 4 | 4 | 8 | 8 |
| 003 | 4/3/2022 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 0 |
| 003 | 4/4/2022 | 3 | 4 | 7 | 8 |
| 003 | 4/5/2022 | 2 | 4 | 6 | 8 |

Comment: This is extremely unclear about how desired output is a function of input. PS Please either ask about 1 bad query/function with the obligatory [mre] & why you think it should return something else at the 1st subexpression that it doesn't give what you expect justified by reference to authoritative documentation or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do & ideally a [mre]. But please ask about the former 1st because misconceptions in the former will get in the way of understanding the latter. And bad code doesn't tell us what you wish it would do. [ask] [Help]

Comment: A [mre] includes cut & paste & runnable code including initialization; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. [ask] [Help] When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. (Debugging fundamental.)

Comment: See [How do comment replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019/266284) to learn to use `@x` to notify 1 non-sole non-poster commenter `x` per comment about that comment. Posters, sole commenters & followers of posts always get notified. Without `@` other commenters get no notification. [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use your date table to cross join with your ID to build a permutation of those two, then you can join ID back into the set and get a full set of ID and Dates along with your real data from your CPRO table.  You could join back in again between MIN and MAX date to remove all the dates in your date table.

```
SELECT X.ID, X.CAL_DT
, COALESCE(T3.EXPRESS,0) EXPRESS
, COALESCE(T3.OTHRES,0) OTHRES
, COALESCE(T3.CPRO_RPT,0) CPRO_RPT
FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT T2.ID, T1.CAL_DT FROM (WORK.QUERY_FOR_DATE t1 CROSS JOIN WORK.QUERY_FOR_CPRO_0000 t2)) X 
LEFT OUTER JOIN WORK.QUERY_FOR_CPRO_0000 T3 
ON X.ID = T3.ID
AND X.CAL_DT = T3.CAL_DT
```

You could also add another join to keep you date range correct if you didn't want to hard code it in the where clause.

```
SELECT 
X.ID
, X.CAL_DT 
, COALESCE(T3.EXPRESS,0) EXPRESS 
, COALESCE(T3.OTHRES,0) OTHRES 
, COALESCE(T3.CPRO_RPT,0) CPRO_RPT 
FROM 
( 
SELECT DISTINCT T2.ID, T1.CAL_DT 
FROM (WORK.QUERY_FOR_DATE t1 
CROSS JOIN WORK.QUERY_FOR_CPRO_0000 t2)) X 
LEFT OUTER JOIN WORK.QUERY_FOR_CPRO_0000 T3 
ON X.ID = T3.ID
AND X.CAL_DT = T3.CAL_DT
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT MIN(DT) AS MINDATE, MAX(DT) AS MAXDATE
FROM WORK.QUERY_FOR_CPRO_000) AS DATEPARAM 
ON X.CAL_DT BETWEEN MINDATE AND MAXDATE
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a Calendar table, you may try the following:

```
Select B.id, C.CAL_DT, COALESCE(D.express, 0) express, COALESCE(D.others, 0) others,
       COALESCE(D.total, 0) total, COALESCE(E.target, 0) target
From Calendar C
Cross Join (Select Distinct id From Table1) B
Left Join table1 D
On D.id = B.id And D.date_ = C.CAL_DT
Left Join table2 E
On E.id = B.id And E.date_ = C.CAL_DT
Order By B.id, C.CAL_DT
```

First, you have to join each id from table1 to every day in your calendar table, and that done by cross join the calendar with the distinct ids from table1.

Now, left join that result to table1, table2 to get which ids not having entries for a specific date (null values).

The `COALESCE` function is used to replace null values with 0.

See a demo using DB2 from [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=864a9dbeb0ed67ef0513259e1b04f8de).